# Is this a bug in xgboost's XGBClassifier?

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost

```py
import numpy as np
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

model = XGBClassifier(
    use_label_encoder=False,
    label_lower_bound=0, label_upper_bound=1
    # setting the bounds doesn't seem to help
)

x = np.array([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ], 'ushort' )
y = [ 1, 1 ]

try :
    model.fit(x,y)
    # this fails with ValueError:
    #  "The label must consist of integer labels
    #  of form 0, 1, 2, ..., [num_class - 1]."
except Exception as e :
    print(e)

y = [ 0, 0 ]
# this works
model.fit(x,y)

model = XGBClassifier()
y = [ 1, 1 ]
# this works, but with UserWarning:
# "The use of label encoder in XGBClassifier is deprecated, etc."
model.fit(x,y)
```

Seems to me like label encoder is deprecated but we are FORCED to use it, if our classifications don't happen to contain a zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved using `use_label_encoder=False` as parameter and the warning message disappear.

I think in your case the problem is that you have only 1 in your `y`, but XGBoost wants the target starting from 0. If you change `y = [ 1, 1 ]` with `y = [ 0, 0 ]` the `UserWarning` should disappear.